# How to call the operator in a template struct

Tags: c++

(I apologize if this is trivial, I'm not well versed in C++ and am trying to learn)

Given

```
template <> struct hash <llvm::Value *> {
    std::size_t operator()(const llvm::Value* val) const {
        std::hash < const llvm::Value*> value_ptr_hasher;
        std::size_t val_hash = value_ptr_hasher(val);
        return val_hash;
    }
};
```

and I have

```
Value * val;
```

How do I get the hash through operator()? Thank you!

Comment: `hash_object(val)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
std::size_t value = hash<llvm::Value *>{}(your_pointer);
```